# MapleBacon.DiskStorage no longer granting access to images after 3.0.0 upgrade: why?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, storage

Following the documentation at https://github.com/zalando/MapleBacon, I created the following, which was working in Swift 2.3:

```
import MapleBacon

fileprivate let
_manager: ImageManager
, _storage: DiskStorage
, _stopwatch: Stopwatch
, _urlsLoading: [ String ]

required init ()
{
    _manager = ImageManager.sharedManager
    _storage = DiskStorage( name: "MyStorageName" )
    _stopwatch = Stopwatch()
    _urlsLoading = []
}

func loadImageBy ( Url url: String )
{
    guard let nsurl = URL( string: url ) else { return }

    _urlsLoading.append( url )

    _manager.downloadImage(
        atUrl: nsurl
        , cacheScaled: true
        , imageView: nil
        , storage: _storage
        , completion:
        {
            [ unowned self ] ( image, error ) -> Void in
            self._stopwatch.startWith( 
                Delay: 0.02
                , ForListener: self._onStopwatchComplete 
            )
        }
    )
}
```

I found that using my own `Stopwatch` component to force a delay of 0.02 enabled `MapleBacon.DiskStorage` to make the images available via its `image( forKey: )` method:

```
fileprivate lazy var _onStopwatchComplete: ( String, Any? ) -> Void =
{
    [ unowned self ] ( key: String, data: Any? ) -> Void in

    var url: String, imageCount = 0

    // loop through urls of images being loaded
    for _ in 0..<self._urlsLoading.count
    {
        url = self._urlsLoading[ imageCount ]

        // image found
        if let img = self._storage.image( forKey: url )
        {
            print( img )
            // remove from list of urls of images being loaded and...
            self._urlsLoading.remove( at: imageCount )
        }

        // image not found: continue waiting
        else
        {
            imageCount += 1
        }
    }

    self._stopwatch.stop()
}
```

With the Swift 3.0 version of MapleBacon though, even a delay of 5 seconds is not producing a reference to the image in `_storage`, and just like the Swift 2.3 version, does not have it in the `completion: ( image, error ) ->` closure either.

With the `3.0.0` version of `MapleBacon`, what does one need to do to successfully both store and retrieve images from `DiskManager`, please?

Thank you [for reading, at least].

**PS**: I do not have the required score to create a `MapleBacon` tag. If anyone does and can, that would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jan Gorman, a contributor to MapleBacon, identified this as a genuine bug in MapleBacon 3.0.0, and uploaded a fix for it (issue trail here: https://github.com/zalando/MapleBacon/issues/38). The code that worked in Swift 2.3 now also works in Swift 3.0.